# After changing build.gradle in app module, I get error: cannot find symbol method setVolumeControlStream

Tags: android

My new `build.gradle` is

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.koran.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
sourceSets { main { res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res', 'src/main/res/animations'] } }
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:15.0.1'
}
```

I changed `compileSdkVersion` to 27, up from 26 (same thing for `targetSdkVersion`).

The only compile error is get is `error: cannot find symbol method setVolumeControlStream(int)`. This method is called from the `onStart()` method of my `MainActivity` (which extends `AppCompatActivity`). I only started getting this error once I changed my gradle file. I'm pretty sure it's because of this line:

`implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0'`

I get an error from this line saying

`All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification`

What does this mean? Why is `setVolumeControlStream` not recognized?

Comment: `buildToolsVersion '27.0.2'`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya same error. and i tried removing `setVolumeControlStream(int)` just to see what happens,and then the line after that also gets an error `cannot resolve symbol`. It did resolve it before the gradle file change.